# Problem with my reboot-on-wifi-lost script

Tags: raspbian, wireless, cron, ping

I have set up my raspberry pi as a small Webserver, connected to a WLAN-Hotspot. I set up a script I found on the internet to reboot the raspi once it looses internet connection or is not able to ping my router. The problem is, it seems like it reboots every XX:07, like 09:07, 10:07 11:07, even though I have set this script on a cronjob which executes every 5 minutes, so this seams really strange to me.

My script:

```
ping -c4 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
  echo "Rebooting" $(date '+%Y %b %d %H:%m') >> /var/www/error.log
  sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
fi
```

Cronjob entry:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sudo -H /usr/local/bin/checkwifi.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The error log:

```
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 03:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 03:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 04:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 04:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 04:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 05:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 06:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 06:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 06:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 06:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 06:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 07:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 07:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 07:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 07:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 08:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 08:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 08:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 08:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 08:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 08:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 08:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 09:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 09:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 09:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 09:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 09:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 09:07
Rebooting 2015 Jul 07 10:07
```

I am using a TL-WN725N wifi adapter with the newest drivers available. I'm pretty sure the hotspot works fine, I don't think it drops out @ every XX:07.

EDIT: my new checkwifi script:

```
ping -c4 192.168.1.1 >> /var/www/error.log

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
  echo "Lost connection" $(date '+%Y %b %d %H:%M') >> /var/www/error.log
  echo $? >> /var/www/error.log
  iwconfig wlan0 >> /var/www/error.log
  sudo ifdown wlan0
  sudo ifup wlan0
  echo "Wlan rebooted"
  iwconfig wlan0 >> /var/www/error.log
fi
```

EDIT2: the new script gave me this output:

```
Lost connection 2015 Jul 07 11:20
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"WIFI"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: CC:A2:23:17:EF:8D   
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=57/100  Signal level=22/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Maybe %m is month? Would fit :P

Comment: @PiotrKamoda Didn't get it. :| :| :|

Comment: @qwertz Script looks fine. Did you monitor if wifi is available at the very same time ? Looks very unusual.

Comment: Seems to me that %m stands for month digit (july == 07)

Comment: Try %M for minute

Comment: @PiotrKamoda will try that now and see if it still happens, assume yes.

Comment: @dastaan how would I do that? Should I just output `iwconfig wlan0` to the log?

Comment: @PiotrKamoda That part is just logging. It has nothing do with cronjob execution. :| :| :|. Btw you're right. It should be %M, not %m as it corresponds to month. +1 for keen observation. :) :)

Comment: @qwertz I would say like PiotrKamoda mentioned, change it to %m to %M. And observe the actual time. See if your wifi is really dropping around that time. Also, instead of making a reboot, you could have just made that interface down and up again.

Comment: @dastaan I changed it to %M now and will see when and how it happens again. Should I just use `ifdown wlan0` and `ifup wlan0`?

Comment: @dastaan, it answers one question, why it does reboot every XX:07, feew times a minute :P (It doesn't ;) )
My guess for the other question is that wifi dongle supports some sort of low current mode when not used. But we have to see what happens in the log ;)

Comment: @PiotrKamoda That could be the case.

Comment: @qwertz I think I have gone through that blog before. There were instructions just making interface up and down in case of connection loss. Follow those instructions. In that case, you won't have to face reboot every time. :)

Comment: @dastaan can you please take a look at the new script in the edited question? :)

Comment: @qwertz Looks good.

Comment: I added the ouput of the new script

Comment: Do you use some kind of wicd-gtk or hdcp-gui (automated wifi configuration)?

Comment: Not that I know of. Also it seems like it restarts wlan now every 5 minutes, so on every cronjob ...

Comment: You should log the output of `ping` and the value of `$?` to check that.

Comment: @goldilocks ok, how would I do that? Just use `ping .......... >> /var/www/error.log`? how do I log the output of `$?`?  `echo $? >> /var/www/error.log`?

Comment: Both of those will work.

Comment: [Slightly off-topic] I'm curious myself what does '$?' actually mean?

Comment: $? is that exit code from the last command

Comment: Whoops, you have to do that right away or save the value -- if you put it after another `echo`, then `$?` will be its return/status value, not `ping`.

Comment: @qwertz If it's logging it every 5 minutes, I advice you to check your wifi configuration. It looks like it's not connected properly.

Comment: @goldilocks will fix that asap and repot back :)

Comment: @dastaan It seems like it is connected properly. I can ping the router, ping the raspi and connect to the internet without problems

Comment: @qwertz, so code in EDIT1 is already proper code? Just curious how it would look in the end ;)

Comment: @PiotrKamoda yes. Surprisingly, so far I haven't had any reboot this night so I'm really happy. Just see what happens next